# Why isn't openlayers detecting touch events from my laptop?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-6

I am developing an app using OpenLayers 6.2.1. To optimize it for mobile devices, I am attempting to increase the hitTolerance when a user touches the screen. [According to the documentation, the map is supposed to be able to detect "touchOnly" events.](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_events_condition.html#.touchOnly) However, when I perform touch interactions on my touchscreen laptop, the event is not detected by my function that responds to touch events:

```
map.on('touchOnly', function() {
    hitTolerance = 5;
    console.log('touch')
});
```

Instead, these touch events trigger my click function. mouseOnly appears to have a similar issue, where events fired from my mouse are detected as click events rather than mouseOnly events. Is there a workaround I can implement?

Quick edit- I am using Google Chrome and am also unable to get touch events to log using the following:

```
map.addEventListener("touchstart", function () {
    hitTolerance = 5;
    console.log('touch');
});
```

Comment: Have you included ol.css from the version you are using?

Comment: Yes I included ol.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ol/Map doesn't fire touchOnly use `singleclick` instead or an other event map can handle such as `movestart`, see https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Map-Map.html
It handles both mouse and touch events at once.

Comment: Correct. touchOnly is a condition, not an event type.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a suitable workaround.

Earlier in my code, I declared the var map as such:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map', 
    view: new ol.View({
        center: [-9099568, 4192168],
        zoom: 3,
        projection: 'EPSG:3857',
    })
});
```

The target "map" refers to this part of my HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
</body>
```

So, I was able to detect touch events on the map using this line:

```
document.getElementById('map').addEventListener('touchstart', function () {
    console.log('touch');
});
```

For some reason the ol map object cannot detect a touch, but its container can.